# How to increase width of underline for the multiline text when on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fellow brothers in code,

I am trying to achieve custom `text-decoration: underline;` effect for the multiline text between `<p>` tags. Similar to one, showed in the picture below.

[image]

Would you mind to share some ideas or solutions for this problem. Do you think it is possible to achieve result with only CSS using `:before` `:after` or is it a case for JS to come in hand?

Many thanks for all possible help.
Will be looking forward.

Comment: I pretty sure it can be done with `:after` and `border`

Comment: I'm thinking background-image on hover.

Comment: Can you add a span?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a bit of [research](https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/) it seems it can be done if you put a `<span>` inside the `<p>` and add a `box-shadow` to that. This works better than a `border` because the `border` has to be displayed below the text only. This allows the underline to intersect the text. This is an added element, but it doesn't require that you break up everything in it's own `<p>` element.

```css
.underline{
  max-width: 240px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.underline:hover span{
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px lightblue;
}
```

```html
  <p class="underline">
    <span>Pick some apples.<br>
    Make some juice. with more text so long that it wraps.<br>
    ????<br>
    Profit!
    </span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Text inside should in one <p> all lines should underline when hover on text.

Comment: Yes, but you still using <p> for every line. It possible when html is: `<p>Let the paint work<br>Share it with a friend<br>Just float around and be there</p>` ?

Comment: After a bit of research looks like you can. But this doesn't intersect the text, still looking into it.

Comment: `border-bottom` will let you set width of underline. Do you think it is possible to set position of the border-bottom and make it overlay with text?

Comment: Finally got it, check the snippet now.

Comment: Nice! This is it, much obliged @Don

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [repeating linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient), and set `display: inline` on the paragraph to draw the lines only under the text:

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 14px, rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.5) 14px, rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.5) 22px);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc imperdiet elementum purus sed fermentum. Aliquam vehicula vel leo ut ullamcorper. <br /> Aenean condimentum justo massa, et eleifend quam elementum at. Mauris vulputate quam ut velit mattis, at pretium
  ex faucibus. Nulla facilisi. <br /> Quisque condimentum sapien ut diam lacinia, non commodo turpis faucibus. Ut in nisl nec magna lobortis tristique ac vitae ante. Cras egestas felis nec tortor varius rhoncus. Phasellus sagittis eget dolor ut condimentum.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can inject a span into the paragraph. If you can, it is simple enough by setting the bottom border.

```css
p:hover > span {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black
}
```

```html
<p><span>Bacon ipsum dolor amet sausage ribeye pastrami, chuck sirloin filet mignon pancetta tail boudin ground round flank pork t-bone turducken. Venison boudin cupim bresaola corned beef meatball pork loin pancetta doner drumstick. Bresaola pork loin fatback pig turkey. Biltong bresaola shoulder cow shankle pork belly brisket ham hock chuck. Meatball drumstick salami pork loin.</span></p>
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to make border to cross with text?

Comment: Look at the picture in the question. You will see that underline overlays with text.

Comment: He want's the border to come up into the text. Almost like a background to the text. This only displays the color below the text, not behind it.

Comment: I understand that, was not clear until OP mentioned it... Looked like a bad MS Paint job. :)

Comment: To get that effect, I think the only thing possible is a background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-shadow` for your case like this:

```css
.custom-underline {
    font-size:200%;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-underline:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 0 violet, inset 0 -3px 0 black
}
```

```html
<p class='custom-underline'>Let the paint work</p>
<br>
<p class='custom-underline'>Share it with a friend</p>
<br>
<p class='custom-underline'>Just float around and be there</p>
```

Comment: @epascarello, can you explain what's the difference?

Comment: Solution will give underline effect for the container, not for the text it self. Try to brake <p> and you will see that it will underline only the last line.

Comment: why the :hover?

Comment: No, your answer does not wrap to multiple lines.... add a large block of text....

Comment: You see the underline is longer than the text. Imagine, that you have post title and you can use only one <p>

Comment: Text inside should in one <p> all lines should underline when hover on text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

I used the `:after` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and gave it `absolute` [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Te render the effect I added a bottom-border to the `pseudo-element` and lift it up a little bit with a `-.35em` `top` which result in it always adjusting to the main element's `font-size`.

Working example:

```css
p span {
  display:inline;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #27196e;
}

p:hover span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top: -.35em;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid rgba(111, 111, 255, .4)
}
```

```html
<p>
<span>Let the paint work</span>
<br/>
<span>Share it with a friend</span>
<br/>
<span>Just float around and be there</span>
</p>
```

Comment: It is a multiline text `<p>Let the paint work<br>Share it with a friend<br>Just float around and be there</p>`

Comment: how to make it on hover? :D

Answer (score 0):

Wrap every phrase inside a `p`, like this:

```
<p>
let the paint work21321321213123321321321  213 
</p>
<p>
let the paint work   
</p>
<p>
let the paint work   
</p>
```

**css**

```
p {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    }

 p::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 130%;
        left: 0%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
```